# Three ways to make Thumbnail browser... help me choose

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 3 ways to make thumbnail browser. Each seems to me like a good way to make it but which route would you as an experienced wpf developer recommend?

1. The easiest is `IValueConverter` which takes path as input and binds to image source.

   ```
   <Image Source="{Binding FullPath, Converter={StaticResource UriToBitmapConverter}, Mode=OneTime, IsAsync=True}" ... />

   public class UriToBitmapConverter : IValueConverter
   {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
       if (value == null) return null;
       BitmapImage img = GetImage((string)value);
       return img;
   }
   ```
2. Control extending image. Uses dependency property to supply path

   ```
   public class MyImage : System.Windows.Controls.Image
   {
     public MyImage()
     {
       this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MyImage_Loaded);
     }
     void MyImage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
       Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
       {
          var source = GetImage(mypath);
          this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => this.Source = source);
       });
     }
   ...
   }
   ```
3. having conversion in a class where I store all the file data, and thumbnail also

   ```
   <Image Source="{Binding Path=MyImage, Mode=OneTime, IsAsync=True}"/>

   public class FileData : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
       private string fullPath;
       public BitmapSource MyImage
           {
               get
               {
                   if (_myimage == null)
                       _myimage = GetImage(fullpath);
                   return _myimage;
               }
           }
   ```

Option 2 seems the best for me as the cleanest way and easy way to load each thumbnail in another thread. Still none of them seem good for browsing network drives and changing folders during long image extractions as I see no way to properly cancel operation.

Comment: Fourth option: Creating a data template for paths or bitmaps when used within an ItemsControl. Paths or bitmaps depends on whether you want to load the images into memory or just want to load them as required when you want to look at them.

Comment: @poke All versions are datatemplates for my FileData class: <DataTemplate x:Key="t1"><Grid>...<Image... If I have virtualization only visible will be loaded, otherwise all. Do you mean something else perhaps?

Comment: I would say, the UI should not care about loading or cancel operations. That can be hidden behind some Service/Business Object. The cancel operation can be just a method on whatever implements `GetImage(mypath)` and can let all open request immediately return some empty image or null.

Comment: If `GetThumbnail` is just loading from a cache URI, you don't need to worry about threads. If you just bind `Image.Source` to the URI, WPF will automatically load it asynchronously. See the [BitmapSource download events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource_events(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I would use WPF to load the image by binding the path string to `Image.Source`. Using an `ItemsControl` you can set the `ItemTemplate` to how you want you items to be displayed, in this case you want an image with the source bound to the FullPath which is of type string. No converter is necessary.

```
<ItemsControl DataContext="{Binding Items}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Image Source="{Binding FullPath}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
 </ItemsControl>
```

If you are looking to only load the images that are visible, then I suggest you create a Panel that can handle virtualization and use that as your ItemsPanelTemplate. An other suggestion for this control to load faster is to create a UserControl that will load the Image in the background and use it in the DataTemplate. Both of these will improve the performance of your application.

Comment: This is the same as my #1 and #3 (see first line in both). Regarding UserControl you are mentioning I think you are talking about #2.

Comment: I never mention anything about using a converter so I don't agree with #1. As for #3 I don't suggest creating a new view model to handle the image load. I do agree that you should create a control to handle the image loading in the background which would allow you to cancel the load if the source has changed or if the control is unloaded.

Comment: In all I have ObservableCollection<FileData> which I populate through GetFiles storing path, size, date and BitmapSource in #3. I don't know about viewmodels so is this considered a new viewmodel you mentioned?